# Align a responsive 25 degree diagonal line in two containers of unknown height

Tags: css

I am trying to align a responsive 25 degree diagonal line with alternate background colors in two containers of unknown height no matter the screen size.

Is this possible in css?

See demo code below. This just about lines up in Example 1 at screen width of about 2000px wide. Other than that, nothing lines up ;).

I can't even get it to work in the first example in two boxes with the same sized content (with  presumably the same height) when the screen size is reduced. I would have thought percentages would work on any sized screen but I must have messed something up.

The second example is more like my required usage where the bottom container is taller with more content.

**Edit 1 per a comment below:** Confirming that I am hoping to achieve one straight diagonal line at the same 25 degree angle running between the two containers regardless of browser width. eg So the bottom of the diagonal line in the first container lines up with the top of the diagonal line in the second container to literally make a straight diagonal line between the two boxes (with alternate background colors in each container).

**Edit 2:** I was wondering why neither examples included the flex code for the ".box .wrapper" container... I realised that I mistakenly missed the dot on the wrapper in the css... apologies for my error. I do want that flex wrapper to be used in the solution(s) to suit existing code in the project.

Any ideas?

Cheers for any help

```css
/*boxes*/
#wrapper{ width: 100%; display: block; position: relative; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; z-index: 0; }
.box { margin: 0; padding: 0; display: block; position: relative; z-index: 1; }
.box2 { margin-bottom: 50px; }
.box .wrapper { width: 80%; z-index: 1; 
display: -webkit-box; display: -ms-flexbox; display: flex;
-webkit-box-orient: horizontal; -webkit-box-direction: normal; -ms-flex-flow: row wrap; flex-flow: row wrap; 
-webkit-box-flex: 1; -ms-flex: 1 0 100%; flex: 1 0 100%; 
-webkit-box-align: center; -ms-flex-align: center; align-items: center; 
-webkit-box-pack: center; -ms-flex-pack: center; justify-content: center; }

/*text*/
body { font-size: 15px; line-height: 1.5; }
h1, h2, h3, p { padding: 0 0 30px 0; margin: 0; }
.box p:last-of-type { padding-bottom: 0; }
h1 { font-size: 3em; }
h2 { font-size: 2.8em; }
h3 { font-size: 2.6em; }
p { font-size: 2em; }

/*colours*/
body { color: #000; }
.box * { color: #fff; }
body {
  --blue: #11c5f9;
  --pink: #f589f4;
}
.box1 { border-bottom: 5px solid #fff; }

/*stripes*/
.stripes { width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0; left: 0; position: absolute; z-index: -1; }
 /*top*/
#stripeA { 
background: var(--aqua); 
background: -o-linear-gradient(335deg, var(--pink) 47.7%, var(--blue) 47.7%); 
background:    linear-gradient(115deg, var(--pink) 48.7%, var(--blue) 48.7%); }
 /*bottom*/
#stripeB { 
background: var(--blue); 
background: -o-linear-gradient(335deg, var(--blue) 44%, var(--pink) 44%); 
background:    linear-gradient(115deg, var(--blue) 44%, var(--pink) 44%); }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">

<h2>Example 1 - Same sized boxes due to same sized content</h2>

<section class="box box1">
 <div class="wrapper">
  <p>same area</p>
  <p>same area</p>
  <p>same area</p>
 </div>
 <div id="stripeA" class="stripes"></div>
</section>
<section class="box box2">
 <div class="wrapper">
  <p>same area</p>
  <p>same area</p>
  <p>same area</p>
 </div>
 <div id="stripeB" class="stripes"></div>
</section>

<h2>Example 2 - Different sized boxes due to different sized content</h2>

<section class="box box1">
 <div class="wrapper">
  <p>smaller area</p>
  <p>smaller area</p>
 </div>
 <div id="stripeA" class="stripes"></div>
</section>
<section class="box box2">
 <div class="wrapper">
  <p>larger area. larger area</p>
  <p>larger area. larger area</p>
  <p>larger area. larger area. larger area. larger area</p>
  <p>larger area. larger area</p>
  <p>larger area. larger area. larger area. larger area</p>
  <p>larger area. larger area</p>
 </div>
 <div id="stripeB" class="stripes"></div>
</section>

</div>
<!-- end #wrapper -->
```

Comment: What is it that you want to align? Do you want the bottom of the first container's diagonal to be at the same place as the top of the second diagonal? If so, at what place? If not, what is it that is required? what if the first container has a very high aspect ratio and the second a very low one and so on?

Comment: Ah sorry that it wasn't clear. I am hoping to achieve one straight diagonal line at the same 25 degree angle running between the two containers. So yes... the bottom of the diagonal line in the first container to line up with the top of the diagonal line in the second container to literally make a straight diagonal line between the two boxes  (with alternate background colors in each container).

Comment: My answer gives a continuous diagonal across the two boxes including the gap between them. i.e. it's 'geometrically correct' but do you want them to shift so they are vertically one above the other (bottom of box1 diagonal and top of box2 diagonal) whatever the gap between the two boxes? This could look 'right' or 'wrong' depending on the size of the gap and the aspect ratios.

Comment: Apologies for the delay in response. I'm not 100% sure what you mean, sorry. The 5px border in between box1 and box2 is to break up the visual (in actual usage this is for a header and a banner box) - the border could just as well be 2px or 10px or not there at all. I guess that adds to the challenge ;). At some point on smaller screen widths part of the diagonals would fall off the screen and not be seen... that is fine. Sorry if I got my wires crossed there

Comment: Hi, my answer puts a diagonal that is continuous across the screen - but you don't see the bit that is the gap between the two elements. My question is whether that is what you want or whether you want the diagonals in each element to shift slightly so the bottom of the diagonal in the top element is vertically above the top of the diagonal in the bottom element. If it's the former is there a problem with my answer? If the latter we need a little bit of calculation!

Comment: That's a good question. I think I get what you mean now. When I was playing with @Termani Afif's solution, I started using this in .box2 `calc(35% + 3px)` instead of 35% - I did it by eye, not sure if it's exactly perfect. Your solution to my eye o.t.o.h. seems to line up without needing a pixel shift. If there was a 10px or 15px  "border" (margin-top for .box2 in your code) below .box1, the offset might be more noticeable... ideally the diagonal line between .box1 and .box2 would line up on exactly the same line irrespective of how thick the "border" was. Probably impossible to calculate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

play with skewing:

```css
body {
  --blue: #11c5f9;
  --pink: #f589f4;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

.box:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  inset: 0 -20%;
  transform: skewX(-25deg);
}

.box1:before {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, var(--blue) 50%, var(--pink)0);
  transform-origin: bottom; /* bottom for the top secton */
}

.box2:before {
  background: linear-gradient(-90deg, var(--blue) 50%, var(--pink)0);
  transform-origin: top; /* top for the bottom section */
}
```

```html
<section class="box box1">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <p>same area</p>
    <p>same area</p>
    <p>same area</p>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="box box2">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <p>same area</p>
    <p>same area</p>
    <p>same area</p>
    <p>same area</p>
    <p>same area</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you Temani. You are a whiz. That lines up so nicely in my testing, even with the 5px border. I made a mistake in my original css code and missed the dot for the .wrapper in ".box .wrapper" - apologies. Can you please provide an update to your answer to include that flex code (it's part of an existing project and the .wrapper needs to be flex)? I tried including the flex in your solution when testing on my end but it made the layout a little off to the left (I messed something up).

Comment: @user3643520 share a link of your code (here) where you added my code. I prefer to keep my code as easy as possible so it benefits any future reader that may have a different layout

Comment: I tried offsetting the code a bit to the rhs of the screen as I think I prefer that by using 65% for `.box1:before { background: linear-gradient(90deg, var(--blue) 65%...` and 35% for `.box2:before { background: linear-gradient(-90deg, var(--blue) 35%...`. That still lines up nicely but I get a very faint "ghost" diagonal towards the LHS of the screen - I guess because of the skewing and the .boxes not being at 50%. Here is a [screencap](https://postimg.cc/KKkzPJWq). Any ideas on how to fix for that faint "ghost line"?

Comment: @user3643520 try to increase the inset value. Use -40% for example instead of -20%

Comment: ah nice. -40% got rid of the diagonal line. as does -30%. thank you kindly

Comment: On narrower screens with this method, a big chunk of the bottom RHS corner gets cut off with what looks like a white triangle fyi... [![Untitled-2.png](https://i.postimg.cc/fLpFBBFc/Untitled-2.png)](https://postimg.cc/8JdtCBTc). I guess the skewing could be turned off below 650px or whatever size the issue appears at. This is tricky

Comment: @user3643520 add background to the section with a pink color so that it covers that part

Comment: @Termani Afifi... I have got myself in a jumble (bit tired)... I will tackle the flex code testing tomorrow and then pasting / reporting here if needed. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Termani Afifi... Great fix, thank you, that fixed the top LH corner of box 1 and the bottom RH corner of box 2.

Comment: This tricky css is new to me... your solution here is brilliant. I have tested it and love how it works. I don't quite understand it all just yet but man is this great. Thank you so much. It's hard to choose a winner between this and @A Harworth's solution as both work so well. I sorted out my flex code btw (I found some related threads here and turns out I needed an extra div to wrap around the paragraph tags - that fixed the issues I was having). In real usage I will not have paragraphs in these boxes and so hadn't encountered the issue I was having before. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

The background is equivalent to the a container for both elements having a background 50% one color, 50% the other color rotated about the mid point of the container except it changes which is the first color depending on whether in box1 or box2.

This effect can be achieved by removing the stripe divs from the main HTML - they are only there for visual effect so this can be moved completely into CSS by putting pseudo before elements on the two boxes.

The trick is that these pseudo elements take on the dimensions and positioning of the entire container, but are prevented from the second overwriting the first by using a clip path.

```css
/*boxes*/

#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.box {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}

.box2 {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.box::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  background-image: linear-gradient(115deg, var(--color1) 0 50%, var(--color2) 50% 100%);
}

.box1::before {
  --color1: var(--pink);
  --color2: var(--blue);
}

.box2::before {
  --color1: var(--blue);
  --color2: var(--pink);
}

.box wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  z-index: 1;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1 0 100%;
  flex: 1 0 100%;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}


/*text*/

body {
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
p {
  padding: 0 0 30px 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.box p:last-of-type {
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 3em;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2.8em;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 2.6em;
}

p {
  font-size: 2em;
}


/*colours*/

body {
  color: #000;
}

body {
  --blue: #11c5f9;
  --pink: #f589f4;
}
```

```html
<h2>Example 2 - Different sized boxes due to different sized content</h2>
<div id="wrapper">

  <section class="box box1">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <p>smaller area</p>
      <p>smaller area</p>
    </div>
  </section>
  <section class="box box2">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <p>larger area. larger area</p>
      <p>larger area. larger area</p>
      <p>larger area. larger area. larger area. larger area</p>
      <p>larger area. larger area</p>
      <p>larger area. larger area. larger area. larger area</p>
      <p>larger area. larger area</p>
    </div>
  </section>

</div>
<!-- end #wrapper -->
```

Note that the whole idea of having a diagonal at 25degrees means that on narrow devices/viewports the diagonal only occurs in the second (taller) element. This is inherent in the geometry whatever method is used in the code. It may be that a steeper angle is what is wanted for narrow viewports in order to get the diagonal effect going across both boxes., but that is outside this question.

Comment: @A Haworth, thank you kindly, that's a very neat solution and is doing what I am looking for. I made a mistake with the flex .wrapper code in my css code (I missed the .). I edited my original post. I will play with your code with fresh eyes tomorrow and see if I can get the flex code working with your diagonals then report back. Please note that when I said 25 degree diagonal, in `background-image: linear-gradient` it is actually a 115deg angle that I am after (like in my original code) - apologies for the confusion. 115deg stacks better on smaller screens too. Thanks and will report back

Comment: I've changed the snippet to 115degrees.

Comment: Thanks for the edits. That's great. Thank you also for the detailed explanation. That is helping me get my head around this really tricky css. I find your solution a little easier to get my ahead around, or look at the code at least ;)

Comment: One thing I experience here that I don't in @Termani's is when using 2 lots of the boxes (like in my og code), I get one diagonal line across all 4 boxes - see [![Untitled-3.png](https://i.postimg.cc/XJNyRPrm/Untitled-3.png)]. Interesting but not quite what I was hoping for. I am aiming for this [![Untitled-4.png](https://i.postimg.cc/1tzHZBXC/Untitled-4.png)] where the diagonal line carries in the two adjacent containers only, and the start position of both .box1's is roughly the same position.

Comment: On smaller screens the diagonals in the top .box1 and .box2 are not shown. I offset the diagonal to 70% btw...`background-image: linear-gradient(115deg, var(--color1) 0 70%, var(--color2) 70% 100%); ` which no doubt affects the diagonals not being visible on smaller screens. Based on that @Termani's might be what I am looking for but interested to see if you have a tweak with your method. Thanks again.